# recursion issue in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```
function syncfile(){
                echo "[ DONE $file ]"
        return ;
}
function syncfolder(){

        folder=$1
        for foo in `ls -1 $folder`
        do

                file="$folder/$foo"

                        if [ -d $file ];then
                                syncfolder $file
                        elif [ -e $file ];then
                                syncfile $file
                        else
                                echo "$file is neither file nor directory"
                        fi
        done
        return;
}
```

above are my two functions for recursions..  when I call   `syncfolder $foldername` it is not giving proper output in following case ..

suppose hierarchy is like below

```
portchanges/
portchanges/script/script1/script1.sh
portchanges/script/script1/script2.sh
portchanges/script/script1/script3.sh

portchanges/script/script4.sh
portchanges/script/script5.sh

portchanges/script6.sh
portchanges/script7.sh

portchanges/appl/script11/script11.sh
portchanges/appl/script11/script12.sh
portchanges/appl/script11/script13.sh
```

now if `foldername=portchanges`
and I call `syncfolder $foldername`

It process only for

```
portchanges/script/script1/script1.sh
portchanges/script/script1/script2.sh
portchanges/script/script1/script3.sh
```

with `function syncfile()` function call...and then it goes to `return` of `syncfolder` function.

it is going to search `script6.sh` and `script7.sh` in `portchanges/script/script1/` directory !! which is totally improper behavior !!

What should I do so It process recursively for entire folder and for every file goes to `syncfile()` function ?

Comment: try adding `syncfile $file` before `syncfolder $file`. A directory will be treated as file first then as a directory.

Comment: but it will not solve my problem .. it searches script6.sh and 
script7.sh in portchanges/script/script1/ directory !! which is totally improper behavior.

Comment: Are you sure there are no aliases in your default env?

Comment: Style nits: no need for -1 in `ls -1` as output isn't to a terminal; useless semicolon after return. Drop the function keyword to make this portable sh syntax. Repeated "!!" make you sound like a dweeb. No spaces before punctuation like !, ?, comma etc.

Comment: Please don't parse `ls` output ([Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). Also, what is your greater goal? There might be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working in my case. if you want to print the directory name, pass it to syncfile.

```
function syncfolder(){
        syncfile $1
        local folder=$1
        for foo in `ls -1 $folder`
        do

                file="$folder/$foo"

                        if [ -d $file ];then
                                syncfolder $file
                        elif [ -e $file ];then
                                syncfile $file
                        else
                                echo "$file is neither file nor directory"
                        fi
        done
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Declare the `folder` variable as `local`. You do not want the recursive call to change the value of the caller's variables.